# Unexpected use of 'pageYOffset' no-restricted-globals

Tags: javascript

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll("nav .container ul li");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
let current = "";<br>
sections.forEach((section) => {
const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;<br>
if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {<br>
  current = section.getAttribute("id");
}
});

navLi.forEach((li) => {
li.classList.remove("active");
```

showing error- Unexpected use of 'pageYOffset'    no-restricted-globals,.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: use `window.pageYOffset` instead of just `pageYOffset`.

Comment: You are not declaring pageYOffset.